# jquery selector such that children don't contain multiple classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to write a selector which selects `<div>`s with `class="my-rating"` only when their children contain none of 3 classes below.

Example html:

```
<div class="my-rating" id="parentA">
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
<div class="my-rating" id="parentB">
</div>
<div class="my-rating" id="parentC">
    <div class="rating-full-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-full-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-full-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-half-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-empty-star"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="my-rating" id="parentD">
    <div class="rating-full-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-full-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-full-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-half-star"></div>
    <div class="rating-empty-star"></div>
</div>
```

Where I want to select `parentA` and `parentB` and exclude C and D.

Something like this:

```
$('.my-rating').children().filter(':not(.rating-full-star):not(.rating-half-star):not(.rating-empty-star)')
```

Except that this guy grabs all the children, not the parent. I also tried:

```
$('.my-rating :not(.rating-full-star,.rating-half-star,.rating-empty-star)')
```

But that's not grabbing too many items. What can I do here?

Comment: That's wildly inefficient, though. Why not just use a class to add to my-rating in specific cases and select it by this added class? You can always remove the class in specific situations again as well. Pretty simple with `$('selector).addClass('myclass')` and `.removeClass('myclass');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
$('.my-rating').not(':has(.rating-full-star, .rating-half-star, .rating-empty-star)');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the child tags selected properly you can just grab the parent from them.

```
$('.my-rating').children().filter(':not(.rating-full-star):not(.rating-half-star):not(.rating-empty-star)').parent();
```

This will return a parent for each child element in the arr, if you only want one since they will be the same for each sibling you can use:

```
$('.my-rating').children().filter(':not(.rating-full-star):not(.rating-half-star):not(.rating-empty-star)').parent()[0];
```

Comment: That'll work if all children have the same parent, but don't think I can use this in scenarios when I have 4 parents to about 20 children? I should update the question accordingly, sorry.

Comment: That is fine, you can just use the first method I posted. It will return an array containing the parent of each child element in your selector. You could then access them with array indexes. 
https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: That should work, but I keep running into edge cases: What if `parentC` contains a child with `class="bar"`? Then the bar child would be selected, and `parent()` would include `parentC`. Is there any way to select on parents first and then filter out by child class second?

Comment: Also since `parentB` has no children, the above won't return `parentB`.